# ORMLite if exists query

Tags: java, ormlite, query-builder

I need some help with ORMLite. I've got ListView with objects downloaded from API. On every item I've got ToggleButton. After clicking on that TB item is added to my database and the TB stata is checked as "clicked". That all is happening in my main fragment but when I switch fragment and come back to main fragment again TB is again set as "unclicked". So, what I need to do is to check when main fragment is being created if object from listView exists in database and if so check ToggleButton status as clicked(I think that would be a correct option) but I don't know how to write query for that :/

Here is my code from adapter that add item to DB :

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   if(isChecked) {
       try {
           final Dao<Concert, Integer> concertDao = getHelper().getConcertDao();
           concertDao.create(concertList.get(position));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about maybe using the `dao.createOrUpdate()` method?  If you are talking about queries, have you looking into the `dao.queryBuilder()`?

Comment: I'm talking about query - I need to check if object is in the database. I tried to use QueryBuilder but don't know how to write query responsible for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lot of ways to accomplish this.  I suggest looking at the [QueryBuilder documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder).  You could obviously do something like:

```
if (concertDao.queryForId(concert.getId()) != null) {
   // the concert exists in the database
}
```

If you don't want to deserialize the object, you could do something like this:

```
if (concertDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("id", concert.getId()).countOf() > 0) {
   // the concert exists in the database
}
```